# jQuery Plugin - How does it work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a little problem:
I don't knwo how to run this jQuery plugin:
http://plugins.jquery.com/project/sound

There's no demo available :(

Comment: Hey - remember to accept an answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [SoundManager 2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), it's well documented, easy to use and doesn't even require jQuery.

Comment: yeah but it DOES require Flash

Answer (score 4):

Apparently the author thought this was documentation enough:

```
$("#sound").sound({swf: url});
$("#sound").load(url);
$("#sound").play();
$("#sound").pause();
$("#sound").stop();
$("#sound").volume(0-100);
```

Here's my interpretation: The element `#sound` is where you audio controller will be. The SWF URL is where on the site you saved the .swf file found in the .zip download. `load()` takes as an argument the URL of the sound file. `play()`, `pause()`, etc. should be self-explanatory. So call `sound()` first, then `load()`, then call `play()` when the time is right.

Try creating your own live demo using such a method, and submit as a bug report on the jQuery site that the plugin demo is down. (There is a link to submit an issue regarding the plugin once you log in.) Perhaps the demo URL will be changed to yours.

Answer (score 0):

i've released an audio player framework that leverages SoundManager2 + integrates w/ jQuery as a $.fn.  very simple to use and/or customize.. similar to jPlayer, but w/ additional features (eg RTMP streaming, full HTML5 support), examples, tests etc:

https://github.com/APMG/APMPlayer